# Why is 'struct Nullable<T>' not a struct?

Tags: c#, struct, nullable

Basically why is the following invalid in C#? I can find plenty of good uses for it and in fact can fix it by creating my own nullable struct class but why and how does the C# specification (and hence the compiler) prevent it?

The below is a partial example of what I'm talking about.

```
struct MyNullable<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value;
    public bool HasValue;

    // Need to overide equals, as well as provide static implicit/explit cast operators
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Compiles fine and works as expected
        MyNullable<Double> NullableDoubleTest;
        NullableDoubleTest.Value = 63.0;

        // Also compiles fine and works as expected
        MyNullable<MyNullable<Double>> NullableNullableTest;
        NullableNullableTest.Value.Value = 63.0;

        // Fails to compile...despite Nullable being a struct
        // Error: The type 'double?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ConsoleApplication1.MyNullable<T>'
        MyNullable<Nullable<Double>> MyNullableSuperStruct;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why you cannot create a nullable nullable? Perhaps if you tried phrasing the question in *words* rather than merely code, you would understand why this does not make much sense.

Comment: @L.B It's similar to a pointer to a pointer to an int.  The double pointer can be null, the pointer can be null, or they can both have a vale. Edit: of course it's not allowed, so it's a moot point.

Comment: I tried to compile your code (in LINQPad) and I get _The type 'int?' **must be a non-nullable value type** in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UserQuery.MyNullable<T>'_. Is this different from when you try to compile it?

Comment: @Cody: I don't think this has any relation to that question.  This one seems to be about the "magic" constraint on `Nullable<T>` that requires the argument to be a *non-nullable* value type.

Comment: @CodyGray I think the answer to that question answers this question, but the questions are different. So the answer is that Nullable is "special" as far as the Runtime is concerned.

Comment: @CodyGray, I wouldn't consider this a duplicate because I'm asking why Nullable<T> does not follow normal struct rules and has a special hack in the compiler. The reason why I'm doing this is because an interface I'm working with requires T where T: struct... I can use MyNullable<Double> but I cannot use Nullable<Double> despite them doign the same exact thing

Comment: Perhaps not. I'll admit the question was fairly unclear to me. You left us to do a lot of reading between the lines. The *title* of the question is rather different from the code sample you seem to be asking about at the bottom.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't agree and voted to reopen. If anything this is an expansion on the previous SO question. A struct IS a value type, thus Nullable<T> IS a value type, however the Runtime treats it differently. That is what this question is asking. Why is Nullable<T> a value type/struct yet NOT a value type/struct.

Comment: @CodyGray, yes sorry I had a hard time explaining what I needed... unfortunately the question was closed almost immediately. `Andrew Finnell` s answer seems to be the best response basically Nullable<T> is a hack in the compiler/runtime and NOT a struct.

Comment: @NtscCobalt I doubt your MyNullable struct does the exact same thing as Nullable.  Can you use it with the `??` operator without boxing?

Comment: `Nullable<double?>` doesn't work either.  It's because of the weirdo morphing behavior, a boxing conversion turns the nullable struct into a System.Nullable *class* object.  Which doesn't meet your contraint.  Also the reason you can't use nullable as a constraint.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm not sure where in my code a Boxing is occurring even with the MyNullable<T> objects there should be zero boxing. If I box a MyNullable<T> that has a nested MyNullable<Double> as type argument T the issue still does not occur because MyNullable<T> consumes a flat compile time known memory area and has no references within it.

Comment: @HansPassant A boxing conversion does not turn a `Nullable<T>` into an instance of a `System.Nullable` class object; `System.Nullable` is a static class.  Boxing turns a `Nullable<T>` into a reference-type instance of `T`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a `struct`. It just doesn't satisfy the value type generic type parameter constraint. From 10.1.5 of the language specification:

> The value type constraint specifies that a type argument used for the type parameter must be a non-nullable value type. All non-nullable struct types, enum types, and type parameters having the value type constraint satisfy this constraint. Note that although classified as a value type, a nullable type (§4.1.10) does not satisfy the value type constraint.

So, the `where T : struct` doesn't mean what you think it means.

> Basically why is the following invalid in C#?

Because `where T : struct` can only be satisfied by `T` that are non-nullable value types. `Nullable<TNonNullableValueType>` does not satisfy this constraint.

> why and how does the compiler prevent it?

Why? To be consistent with the specification. How? By performing syntactic and semantic analysis and determining that you've supplied a generic type parameter `T` that doesn't satisfy the generic type constraint `where T : struct`.

> [I] can fix it by creating my own nullable struct class but

No, you're version doesn't fix it. It's basically exactly the same as `Nullable<T>` except you don't get special handling by the compiler, and you're going to cause some boxing that the compiler's implementation won't box.

> I can find plenty of good uses for it

Really? Such as? Keep in mind, the basic idea of `Nullable<T>` is to have a storage location that can contain `T` or can represent "the value is missing." What's the point of nesting this? That is, what's the point of `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`? It doesn't even make conceptual sense. That might be why it's prohibited, but I'm merely speculating (*Eric Lippert has [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196570/why-is-struct-nullablet-not-a-struct/10196758#comment13092154_10196664) that this speculation is correct*). For example, what is an `int??`? It represents a storage location that represents the value is missing or is an `int?`, which is itself a storage location that represents the value is missing or is an `int`? What's the use?

Comment: I think the OP's real question is "Why does 10.1.5 include `Note that although classified as a value type, a nullable type (§4.1.10) does not satisfy the value type constraint.`"?

Comment: @Gabe I also don't agree with this. Jason's answer is perfect. 10.1.5 tells the OP exactly why his code doesn't work.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell that depends on whether the OP is trying to find out the reason behind the language design.  Questions about "why doesn't my code work" can be answered by "because the language was designed like this"; questions about "why was the language designed like this" cannot.

Comment: @phoog Yes you are right. They are two different questions and it isn't exactly obvious which one is being asked. Probably leaning more towards what Gabe is saying now that I re-read it, because of the "finding valid uses for it"

Comment: My question is aimed at the motive behind the language design because I can design a work around as shown in the code.

Comment: @NtscCobalt: I have attempted to answer the motive with my last paragraph. I'll turn the question on you? What is your use case?

Comment: My use case is TArg1 = Nullable<Double> in the class TypedPageCommand<TArg1, TArg2>
        where TArg1 : struct
        where TArg2 : struct

Comment: @NtscCobalt: That's it? Then just use `TArg1 = Double` and throughout your code use `Nullable<TArg1>` everywhere. What's the big deal?

Comment: @Jason, I don't have access to the code within TypedPageCommand so I can't wrap every usage of TArg1 within it with Nullable. TypedPageCommand calls a delegate function with TArg1 and TArg2 as params later on.

Comment: Your speculation is correct. In the original design of the feature, `int??`, `int???` and so on were perfectly legal, and in fact there is still a small amount of code in the compiler left over from the original prototype to deal with precisely those situations. Of course that code is now only exercised in error-recovery codepaths.

Comment: @EricLippert: Can you provide any insight as to why the spec does not allow a `Nullable<T>` to satisfy a value type constraint? Is it strictly to prevent `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`?

Comment: @Gabe: That is a good reason but it is not the *only* reason. For example, this means that in `void M<T>(T t) where T : struct { object o = t; Debug.Assert(o != null); }` the assertion is correct. It would be quite confusing if you could box something determined to be a value type and have null come out the other end!

Comment: @Gabe: Or even better, `Debug.Assert(o is T);`, which would be false if T were a nullable struct and t were null.

Comment: @EricLippert, I'm curious why `Nullable<T>` boxes the `T Value` of the nullable struct instead of the entire `Nullable<T>`. Seems very confusing and different from boxing of every other struct.

Comment: @NtscCobalt this blog post explains the decision process very nicely: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2005/08/11/450640.aspx

Comment: @NtscCobalt: It was a controversial decision that caused a lot of debate back in the day; as soma notes in the article phoog links to, the final decision was made quite late in the ship cycle for .NET v2.0. The moral of the story is of course **design nullability and non-nullability into your type system from day one** rather than trying to bolt it on later. Next time you design a type system, keep that in mind.

Comment: @EricLippert: I think the real problem stems from the notion that something like an empty `Nullable<int>` should compare equal to any other kind of null.  That's the only reason I can see for not boxing a valueless `Nullable<int>` as what it naturally is--a `Nullable<int>` whose `HasValue` field is `false`.  Lose the goofy boxing behavior and there's no reason not to allow `Nullable<T>` for all `T`, redundant or not.

Comment: @Jason: One good use for being able to declare `Nullable<T>` for arbitrary `T` would be for `TryGetValue`-style routines.  Passing the return value as a `ref` parameter is icky and precludes any possibility of covariance.  A `TryGettableCollection<T>` where `T` is constrained to `class` could return `null` when no data is available; one where `T` is constrained to `struct` could return a `Nullable<T>`.  It would be cleaner, though, if one collection could handle reference types and value-types interchangeably; only the `struct` constraint on `Nullable<T>` prevents it.

Answer (score 2):

One reason for the struct constraint's diallowing nullables is that we want to be able to use `T?` in generic methods.  If `struct` permitted nullable value types, the compiler would have to prohibit `T?`.

The nullable type must have special handling in the compiler in other cases as well:

- The null keyword must be implicitly convertible to a nullable type; this is impossible with a value type.
- Nullable value types can be compared with the null keyword; with non-nullable value types, this comparison always returns false.
- Nullable value types work with the `??` operator; non-nullables do not.

Comment: If Nullable's T type argument constraint truly was struct and Nullable truly derived from struct then T? would just wrap a Nullable around whatever T was. So Nullable<T?> would be Nullable<Nullable<T>>

Comment: @NtscCobalt: And `Nullable<Nullable<T>>` is a useless concept.

Comment: @Jason, perhaps but using Nullable<T> for a type argument requiring T be a struct makes sense as Nullable<T> is defined as struct Nullable<T> : where T struct { T Value; bool HasValue;} so logically it may be confusing but there should be no reason for the compiler to prevent it (other than specification).

Comment: @NtscCobalt: Suppose it were legal. What about this: `Nullable<int> w = null; Nullable<Nullable<int>> x = w;` Then `x.HasValue` evaluates to true but `x.Value.Value` and `x.Value.GetType()` throw. Gross. The concept just doesn't make any sense. So `x` represents an instance of `Nullable<int>` that is not missing, but it is....

Comment: @NtscCobalt to expand on Jason's comment: How would you handle operator lifting in a world where nullables could be nested arbitrarily deeply?

Comment: @Jason actually it wouldn't because x.Value.Value is still there due to the fact that in the struct world all values exist at their default value if they are not set. Consider the C-style struct `struct Inner { public: Double Value; bool HasValue;} struct Outer { public: Inner Value; bool HasValue;}` The moment I create an Outer, Outer.Inner is allocated as well because it actually lives in the memory space of Outer. The values are not initialized (C rules) but the space for them was correctly allocated and they are usable without any exceptions.

Comment: @NtscCobalt `Value` is a property getter, not a field, and it throws an exception if `HasValue` is false.

Comment: @Phoog yes I understand that x.value.GetType() throws if x.HasValue = false because of the implementation of the property not an issue of there not being a value to call GetType() on which is what I thought `Jason` was originally trying to say.

Comment: @NtscCobalt aha, I missed that.  You are correct that if x.HasValue is true then x.Value.GetType() will not throw.

Comment: @phoog: It's easy to get confused here. If you have `Nullable<int> w` and `w.HasValue` is false `then w.GetType()` will throw. Now consider `Nullable<Nullable<int>> x = w` where `w` is such that `w.HasValue` is `false`. Then `x.Value` is a copy of `w` and so `x.Value.GetType()` will throw because `w.GetType()` throws. However, `x.HasValue` is true but `x.Value` represents a `null` instance of `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: @Jason, x.Value would return w, not w.Value so in your case where x.Value.GetType() would return `typeof(Nullable<Int>)` not throw or return `typeof(Int)`

Comment: @NtscCobalt aha, Jason corrects me: I had forgotten that when you call `GetType()` on a struct, *the struct is boxed.* Therefore, if `x.HasValue` is false, `x.GetType()` *will* throw.  It throws a NullReferenceException rather than an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @NtscCobalt: Nope. If `w` is `Nullable<T>` and `w.HasValue` is false then `w.GetType()` throws. It's because `w` will be boxed on the call to `GetType` and it will be boxed to a null reference. Therefore, it will not return `typeof(Nullable<int>)`. It will throw.

Comment: @Jason, oh hmm sorry I wasn't aware that Nullable<T> is boxed to (Object)(this.Value). It does make sense. I actually assumed that calls to `ValueType.GetValue()` was replaced at compile time with `typeof(ValueType)`

Comment: @NtscCobalt: No, the compiler can't do that! What happens here: `Base b = new Derived(); Console.WriteLine(b.GetType()).` If the compiler could do the replacement that you suggest, it would return print `Base` instead of `Derived`.

Comment: @NtscCobalt: Here's a vastly simpler way to understand the point that I'm making. Consider this method: `bool AmINull<T>(T t) where T : struct { object o = t; return o == null; }`. Suppose that `T = Nullable<Nullable<int>>` is allowed. Now: `Nullable<int> w = null; Nullable<Nullable<int>> x = w;` Note that `x.HasValue` is `true` meaning that `x == null` is `false` **however** `AmINull(x)` will return `true`. Why? Well, it would box the value of `x`, which is a instance of `Nullable<int>` which would be boxed to a `null` reference. So `x == null` is `false` yet `AmINull(x)` is `true`. Not cool.

Comment: @Jason, structs cannot have inheritance so you can't do `Base b = new Derived()` where `Base` is a struct

Comment: @Jason but all of a value type's base classes are reference types, so the compiler in theory *could* replace `valueType.GetType()` with `typeof`; that replacement wouldn't apply when you box the value type to one of its reference type base classes.

Comment: @Jason: The problem, fundamentally, is that someone decided that calling `Object.Equals` on (`null`) and (a `Nullable<T>` whose `HasValue` field is `false`) should return `true`.  Lose that silliness, and calling `GetType()` on a `Nullable<int>` would return a `Nullable<int>`, whether it has a value or not.  To allow for passing to code which will expect either a boxed `T` or a null, the `Nullable<T>` type could include an `AsObjectOrNull` property which would return either `Value` cast to `Object` or else `null`.  No problem with nested `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`; that property would...

Comment: ...return `null` if the outer `HasValue` was false, or else would return a boxed `Nullable<T>` which might or might not have a value.